# Is there a performance hit in having a large dbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm building a web app that will have 30-35 tables in one database.  Now the thing is I want to split the app into 3 different front ends (different teams want different things).  3 different projects.

App1 might use 15-20 tables, App2 might use 10, App3 might use 15.

I was planning on making a project called Models that has a dbContext with all the tables in the database and use that for the web app projects.  If I need to add or update the database I can just update that one models project.

A colleague mentioned that you should only include what you need so I should make 3 separate dbcontexts for each web project or there will be a performance hit for including unnecessary tables.

Comment: I don't think there will be any non-negligible perfomance hit, but splitting is still good for different reasons.

Comment: 30-35 tables is a rather small number, as I've worked with `DbContext` with hundreds (closing in on the thousand) of tables. The performance hit (if any at all) will be upon the first ever initialization when the context is configured. However, one vs many is an opinionated question and the answer is "it depends"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I disagree that this question is an opinionated one. The only question being asked is in the title, and it is a yes/no question. That said, it looks like you have provided an answer to that question based on real-world experience with your comment, and it would make sense if you actually turn it into an answer.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks, I've added an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: no, I haven't seen any performance hit with extremely large `DbContext`s. In one project I've worked, where the `DbContext` was defined with close to a thousand `DbSet`s, the configuration time (the time taken to perform the calls to `OnConfiguring` and `OnModelCreating`) was around 2 seconds, and every single entity was configured through the Fluent API; so you can say that the hit is negligible (if there's one at all) for only 35 entities.

That said, whether you use one or more `DbContext` is dependent of how you will use them. If there's a clear separation of data where you can clearly say "this table will only be used here" and you will not end up having repeated `DbSet`, you could keep them separated.

Answer (score 7):

> A colleague mentioned [...] there will be a performance hit for including unnecessary tables

When colleagues say things like that, you tell them to either back such claims with evidence or to shut up. Seriously, there's enough cargo cult programming in the world already. It's the same as colleagues enforcing you to use `String.Empty` because it's faster than using `""`, because they read that on a blog once. Hint: it isn't.

It's very healthy to apply criticism to every claim you hear, especially if that claim is not grounded in any reality whatsoever.

Yes, loading a type with more properties will require more disk I/O and more CPU cycles. This will be extremely negligible though. You will *not* notice this on the grand scale of things.<sup>*</sup>

It becomes quite a different story if you're using an EDMX though, as loading and parsing that 5 MB of metadata will literally add *seconds* to the loading time of your application.<sup>*</sup>

<sub><sup>*</sup>: yes, I'm looking for sources for both those claims at the moment.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think its not a problem from performance perspective - but definitely I see challenge from maintenance perspective.

I experienced similar situation where we had one edmx based data model shared across different capabilities. however each capability is just focused on specific number of tables.

With this, problem we started facing whenever we required to change any table specific to any capability required us to touch one single data model and also leads to unnecessary merge conflicts during checkins.